# '90s-2000s science fiction movie about a group of hackers

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, religion

A group of hackers are hacking in the Pentagon/Vatican to resolve the Bible code. The one guy at the end becomes godlike. One girl, two boys and a reporter, I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***[Beacon77](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1436571/?ref_=ttpl_pl_tt)***, also known as *The 7th Dimension* (2009)...?

From IMDB:

> Two young women arrive at a curious penthouse apartment, led by one's crush on her tutor. However, her love interest doesn't live alone. He's part of a trio of computer hackers about to embark on the ultimate job on the world's most mysterious mainframe. Whilst doing so, they unlock more than they bargain for with supernatural and ultimately fatal results. Can this seemingly insignificant chain of events, which have thrown this group together, be construed as fate? Can the beacon provide a signal of hope or is it a web of manipulation, paranoia and ultimately... murder?

From a [review](https://www.eyeforfilm.co.uk/review/the-7th-dimension-film-review-by-paul-griffiths):

> Zoe (Lucy Evans) has a crush on her tutor Malcolm (David Morton) and persuades her student friend Sarah (Kelly Adams, Bronson) to accompany her to his low-rent penthouse flat. They find that Malcolm lives with frosty Kendra (Calita Rainford), wheelchair-using pirate radio jock Declan (Jonathan Rhodes) and rows of computers and banks of monitors.
>
> **It turns out that the trio are Beacon 77, super-IT geniuses trying to hack into the Vatican’s mainframe and access the ‘real’ Torah. Once in, they can crack the legendary Bible Code, unravelling words and phrases that will reveal the prophecies of mankind.** The codes to life, everything and everyone mapped, in the past and future, laid out in the texts not just in three dimensions, but in four, five or… yada yada.
>
> More than fate would have it that they start cracking the night Kelly and Lucy drop in. **It’s a close global cyber run-off against the Vatican controls, though. Then the flat goes into lockdown, the Pentagon starts crashing their systems, mysterious psychic forces appear, telepaths come a-knocking on heads and super-brain Declan has a few more ideas.**